# How to do math with list in php

Tags: php, list

This is my problem; I have two lists which are arrays of names:

```php
$my_array = array("ben", "alax", "jeff", "peter");
list($a, $b, $c, $d);

$my_array2 = array("ben", "alax");
list($a, $b);
```

so what I want to do is to divide the elments of my_array2, through my_array and then times 100.
so in math terms it would look something like this:

```
50 / 100 * 100 = 50%
```

I want to see that 50% of the names in the second array has returned.
could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `list()` is in the mix, but if you want to work out the difference between two arrays use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and then count them, use that number to do your math.

```
<?php
$my_array = array("ben", "alax", "jeff", "peter");
$my_array2 = array("ben", "alax");

$diff = array_intersect($my_array, $my_array2);

echo count($diff) / count($my_array) * 100 . '%';
?>
```

https://3v4l.org/cXCOX

**Result:**

```
50%
```

Make sure that you skip the whole process if `$my_array` is empty.

Comment: @nordin actually you want `array_intersect` not `array_diff` sorry.